# ANTLR4 RuleContext.Inspect() No longer Exist?

Tags: antlr4

According to the Sam Harwell's previous reply to my question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294778/antlr4-api-to-display-arbitrary-parsetree), there is a RuleContext.Inspect() method that I can invoke in my own code to inspect an arbitrary part of the parse tree. But it seems that it is no longer available now. Was it moved to somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it here: `org.antlr.v4.gui.Trees.inspect`